# I have a radio button in UWP XAML for "Pregnancy Status" which should be enabled only when the Gender radio button is selected as "female"

Tags: .net, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

```
<RadioButton x:Name="radioButton3"  TabIndex="14" GroupName="PregnancyStatus" Content="Yes" IsChecked="{Binding PatientInfo.PregnancyStatus, Converter={StaticResource pregnancyStatusConverter}, ConverterParameter=Yes, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
<RadioButton x:Name="radioButton4"  TabIndex="15" GroupName="PregnancyStatus"  Content="No" IsChecked="{Binding PatientInfo.PregnancyStatus, Converter={StaticResource pregnancyStatusConverter}, ConverterParameter=No, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
<RadioButton x:Name="radioButton5"   TabIndex="16" GroupName="PregnancyStatus" Content="Unknown" IsChecked="{Binding PatientInfo.PregnancyStatus, Converter={StaticResource pregnancyStatusConverter}, ConverterParameter=Unknown, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
```

How can i make this radio button enabled only when gender radio button is "female", For "male" i should't be able to edit this button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `IsEnabled` property. Let's say that your female gender radio button is has `x:Name` of `radioFemale`. You would then add a `IsEnabled` property binding as follows:

```
IsEnabled="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=radioFemale}"
```

This means that once the female radio button is checked, the enabled property will be true, and the other way around. So for your code:

```
<RadioButton x:Name="radioButton3"  
   IsEnabled="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=radioFemale}"
   TabIndex="14" GroupName="PregnancyStatus" Content="Yes" 
   IsChecked="{Binding PatientInfo.PregnancyStatus, Converter={StaticResource pregnancyStatusConverter}, ConverterParameter=Yes, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
<RadioButton x:Name="radioButton4" 
   IsEnabled="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=radioFemale}"
   TabIndex="15" GroupName="PregnancyStatus"  Content="No" 
   IsChecked="{Binding PatientInfo.PregnancyStatus, Converter={StaticResource pregnancyStatusConverter}, ConverterParameter=No, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Command="{Binding PregnancyStatusCommand}" />
<RadioButton x:Name="radioButton5" 
   IsEnabled="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=radioFemale}"
   TabIndex="16" GroupName="PregnancyStatus" Content="Unknown" 
   IsChecked="{Binding PatientInfo.PregnancyStatus, Converter={StaticResource pregnancyStatusConverter}, ConverterParameter=Unknown, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
```